# How to prevent overwriting in loop

Tags: javascript

Steve and his family went to 5 different restaurants. The bills were $124, $48, $268, $180 and $42.
Steve likes to tip 20% of the bill when the bill is less than $50, 15% when the bill is between $50 and $200, and 10% if the bill is more than $200. I am creating this program in javascript and I am not able to store seperate values in the array. Please guide me how to do that.

This is the code

```
let bill = [48, 42, 124, 180, 268];

let x, tip1, tip2, tip3, total1, total2, total3;

let tip;

let total;

class Tip {

    TipCalc() {

        for (x of bill) {

            if (x < 50) {
                tip1 = x * 0.20;
                total1 = x + tip1;
            }

            if (x >= 50 && x < 200) {
                tip2 = x * 0.15;

                total2 = x + tip2;
            }

            if (x >= 200) {
                tip3 = x * 0.10;
                total3 = x + tip3;
            }

            tip = [tip1, tip2, tip3];
            total = [total1, total2, total3];
        }



        console.log('tip array ' + tip);

        console.log('total array ' + total);
    }



}

let t1 = new Tip();
t1.TipCalc();
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: What is the expected output? I see you code output is ```tip array 8.4,27,26.8
total array 50.4,207,294.8```

Comment: You can "store separate values in arrays" in multiple ways, often using [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Would be a nice idea to just use a search engine for questions like this next time. Good luck.

Comment: it should be tip array 9.6,8.4,18.6,27,26.8  total array 57.6,50.4,142.6,207,294.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the values in arrays, like this:

```js
let bill = [48, 42, 124, 180, 268];
let x;
let tipValue, tip;
let tips = [], totals = [];

class Tip {

  TipCalc() {
    for (x of bill) {
      if (x < 50) {
        tipValue = 0.2;
      } else if (x >= 50 && x < 200) {
        tipValue = 0.15;
      }else if (x >= 200) {
        tipValue = 0.1;
      }

      tip = (x * 100 * tipValue) / 100;
      tips.push(tip);
      totals.push(x + tip);
    }

    console.log('tip array ' + tips);
    console.log('total array ' + totals);
  }
}

let t1 = new Tip();
t1.TipCalc();
```

note the multiplication is done in integer to avoid rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to have the *tips* as array, just use a function and `.map` over the `bill`-Array you already have:

```js
let bill = [48, 42, 124, 180, 268];

function calcTip(billingVal) {
  return billingVal < 50
    ? billingVal * 0.2
    : billingVal < 200
    ? billingVal * 0.15
    : billingVal * 0.1;
}

let tips = bill.map(calcTip);

console.log('tips:', tips);
```

If you also need the total array, you can re-use the `calcTip` function and do *exactly the same*:

```js
let bill = [48, 42, 124, 180, 268];

function calcTip(billingVal) {
  return billingVal < 50
    ? billingVal * 0.2
    : billingVal < 200
    ? billingVal * 0.15
    : billingVal * 0.1;
}

function calcTotal(billingVal) {
  return billingVal + calcTip(billingVal);
}

let tips = bill.map(calcTip);
let totals = bill.map(calcTotal);

console.log('tips:', tips);
console.log('totals:', totals);
```